# How to grant permissions to Webapp Web Analytics Reports in Central Administration

Tags: permissions, central-administration, web-analytics

My management department asks for access on the Web Analytics reports for the whole web application. I tried giving them the permissions to see Web Analytics, but they are still not able to login into Central Administration. Is there a possibility granting them acces to the reports, without giving them CA Administration rights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

freaky,

Making everyone a Farm Administrator on Central Admin is not a good idea, you should ask them to see Site Collection and Site level Web Analytics Data instead of whole Web Application!

However, one way is to put user in `Security -> Manage the farm Administrators Group -> [Add user in this group]` and now they should see Web Analytics Reports

**About Site Collection and Site level Web Analytics Reports:**
Out-of-the-box, these reports are visible to Administrators at each level.  For example, site-level reports are available to Site Administrators of those sites.  And there is also a new permission level, `“View Web Analytics Data”` that will allow users to access these reports without having to give them Administrator privileges.

You can access Web Analytics reports by going to `Site Actions -> Site Settings`.  Under the Site Actions heading you will see two links, `Site Web Analytics Reports and Site Collection Web Analytics Reports.`

[Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2010/03/21/introducing-web-analytics-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

Comment: Thats another great strike of MS -.- Allowing only admins to see whos clickin where.. I know that i could use Sitecollectionwide Reports, but we have Sitecollections per department + projects .. As i said i dont want to give people acces to the Farm Admin Group, who technically dont know alot of this.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2010, there is a permission called `View Web Analytic Data - View reports on Web site usage`. You can create a group having Read + this permission.

**EDIT:**

Try configuring permissions by following [these steps](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg266382.aspx#vwad) and after it you can create a Web Analytics Web Part (located at the end of the linked article) in a site where they have access to.

Comment: I did that, but not-admin users are still not allowed to login into CA.